# Is there a better way to retrieve lists of object from Firebase in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have been playing with Firebase in my Android app and have been having trouble with reading data from the DB. I store a list of objects that contains some properties as well as another list of other objects inside the DB. While the storing works fine, I can't seem to easily get the data back. I'd ideally like to cast directly to an object (or even to the list) but here is what I came up with:

```
    app.db.child(app.UID).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        for (trip in it.children) {
            val name = trip.child("name").value as String
            val description = trip.child("description").value as String
            val tripDate = trip.child("tripDate").value as Long
            val isActive = trip.child("active").value as Boolean
            val dateCreated = trip.child("dateCreated").value as Long
            val dateCompleted = trip.child("dateCompleted").value as Long
            val id = trip.child("id").value as String

            val travel = Travel(name, description, tripDate, isActive, dateCreated, dateCompleted, id)
            println(travel.toString())
            for (stop in trip.child("stops").children) {
                val stopName = stop.child("name").value as String
                val stopNotes = stop.child("notes").value as String
                val complete = stop.child("complete").value as Boolean
                val dateTime = stop.child("dateTime").value as Long
                val stopId: Int = (stop.child("id").value as Long).toInt()

                travel.stops.add(TripStop(stopName, dateTime, stopNotes, stopId, complete))
            }
            app.data.add(travel)
        }
    }
```

While it does work, I can't help but feel there is a better way to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

P.S. I'm only trying to get the data once (once the application opens), so the event listeners on data change don't really make sense

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin expert, but I've seen people use Kotlin data classes with Firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bkotlin%5D+data. Aside from the Kotlin aspects, these are the same as the `Post.class` you see in the Firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Besides that, I think that this article, [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) and also this, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) might help.